# Do I need to download all .proto files in Android framework source codes in order to parse proto message of adb dumpsys?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, proto

In order to parse proto message, I need to have a python class file generated by the template(.proto) file.

But in case of the Android, I had to download `framework/base`, `framework/proto_logging` and possibly more repos to `import` all related proto files.
I attached my target proto file `activitymanagerservice.proto` at the end of this ticket.

So my question is:

- Should I find and download all proto files to generate a python class?
- If so, should I manage versions of proto files? for example, Android9's dumpsys and Android12's dumpsys might different

Here is the reason why I am figuring out this:

> What I am doing currently is collecting `meminfo` and other
> performance metrics every seconds offered by `adb shell dumpsys`.
>
> Without `--proto` I had to use regex of python but sooner I realized
> that there are too many conditions I had to consider.
>
> Since they offer `--proto` option I am looking into Protocal Buffer.

The command I am using is:

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo --local -s --proto com.android.chrome | protoc --decode_raw`

And the result looks like:

```
1: 202730922
2: 268724137
4 {
  1 {
    1: 29432
    2: "com.android.chrome"
    9 {
      1: 6128
      2: 26032
      3: 45932
      4: 40
      5: 44628
      6: 5044
      7: 29509
      8: 461
    }
  }
}
```

Since this is ambiguous, I found the right proto file but it has many imports:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/proto/android/server/activitymanagerservice.proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package com.android.server.am;

import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/app/activitymanager.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/app/appexitinfo.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/app/notification.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/app/profilerinfo.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/content/component_name.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/content/configuration.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/content/intent.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/content/package_item_info.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/internal/processstats.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/os/bundle.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/os/looper.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/os/powermanager.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/server/intentresolver.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/server/windowmanagerservice.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/util/common.proto";
import "frameworks/base/core/proto/android/privacy.proto";
import "frameworks/proto_logging/stats/enums/app/enums.proto";

...

message MemInfoDumpProto {
    option (.android.msg_privacy).dest = DEST_AUTOMATIC;

    optional int64 uptime_duration_ms = 1;
    optional int64 elapsed_realtime_ms = 2;

    message ProcessMemory {
        option (.android.msg_privacy).dest = DEST_AUTOMATIC;

        optional int32 pid = 1;
        optional string process_name = 2;

        message MemoryInfo {
            option (.android.msg_privacy).dest = DEST_AUTOMATIC;

            optional string name = 1;
            // The proportional set size for the heap.
            optional int32 total_pss_kb = 2;
            // The proportional set size that is swappable for the heap.
            optional int32 clean_pss_kb = 3;
            // The private dirty pages used by the heap.
            optional int32 shared_dirty_kb = 4;
            // The shared dirty pages used by the heap.
            optional int32 private_dirty_kb = 5;
            // The shared clean pages used by the heap.
            optional int32 shared_clean_kb = 6;
            // The private clean pages used by the heap.
            optional int32 private_clean_kb = 7;
            oneof dirty_swap {
                // The dirty the pages that have been swapped out.
                int32 dirty_swap_kb = 8;
                // The dirty the pages that have been swapped out, proportional.
                int32 dirty_swap_pss_kb = 9;
            }
            // The rss set size for the heap.
            optional int32 total_rss_kb = 10;
        }
        message HeapInfo {
            option (.android.msg_privacy).dest = DEST_AUTOMATIC;

...

message StickyBroadcastProto {

...
```

Answer (score 0):

As activitymanagerservice.proto has lots of imports, I had download all related files

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/proto_logging

and then compiled not only my message class but also all other proto files:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto --python_out=proto_out proto/**/*.proto
```

This is because they reference each other.

I could finally read `dumpsys` result of proto enabled. But still, I am not sure if this is the right approach.